# Where can I find a good theoretical treatment of conductor shielding?

Tags: capacitance, field, conductors

Suppose one has three current carrying cylinders lying on the same plane. Some of the electric field of the first conductor ends up on the second conductor, which creates capacitance \$C_{12}\$. But also some of the field lines of the first conductor end up on the third conductor, also creating capacitance \$C_{13}\$. I am trying to find a theoretical derivation of the value of \$C_{13}\$. All I am finding so far is people extracting the value of \$C_{13}\$ using quasi-static field solvers.

Comment: I am sure there should be 70' and 80' literature solving this kind of problem by hand, but i believe the standard approach here is to use 2D/3D Electrostatic FEM solvers as you said. Standard electrical codes, such as NEMA, NEC, IEC among others also deal with the topic of conductor shielding, but for standard conductor (cable, stranded or solid) purposes -not as generic conductor cylinders. If you are still concerned and this question is still valid, you could give deeper details on the application, frequencies, voltages, etc. in order to give a proper answer....

Answer (score 1):

A good book on the subject is Charles S. Walker's book "Capacitance, Inductance, and CrossTalk Analysis" (Artech House). Common configurations of conductors with or without ground plane are presented, with either exact or approximate formulas, graphs and references to more material. Your library may have it.